# How do i make this kind of menu for my wear os watchface?

Tags: java, android, wear-os, watch-face-api

I'm trying to create a watch face and trying to implement customizability. So when I saw a "Styles" option on the Elements Digital I found this as a perfect implementation. Since I down own a Wear OS watch yet, IDK how people make their watch faces customizable. Is it though the Wear OS app? Or a separate app that allows you to do that? Or the way I'm trying to achieve?
Well if you have an answer I will gladly try it.

A picture of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: A photo of what im trying to achive]

Many thanks, NgNority

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to provide customization options is by creating a configuration screen for your watch face. You can find more information about how to do that in the official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/configuration).

There are some really good samples on the official Wear OS GitHub page:
https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples

You might want to take a look at the configuration example [here](https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples/tree/master/WatchFace/Wearable/src/main/java/com/example/android/wearable/watchface/config).